# DAR LA SOLUCION A ESTO ESTO LO AGRADECERIA MUCHO

Tags: php

TENGO ESTE ERROR QUE ME SALE A LA HORA DE EJECUTAR ME CODIGO Y NO SE COMO SOLUCIONARLO
GRACIAS
ESTE ERROR QUE ME SALE :

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd1/837/18664837/public_html/ropainfantil.php on line 167
No se pudo conectar a la base de datos. }else { ?>
```

ESTA ES LA LINEA QUE ME DA EL ERROR:

```php
if ($SQL = mysqli_connect('localHost','id184837_','MI CONTRASEÑA') and mysqli_select_db('id1866')) {
```

Y ESTE ES EL CODIGO ENTERO:

```
<?php
    if ($SQL = mysqli_connect('localHost','id18664837_mo','s(1TE~D7eze2E^_?') and mysqli_select_db('id18664837_mm')) {
    
        $SQL = "SELECT ropainfantil.Id_Album ,ropainfantil.Descripcion ,ropainfantil.precio , DATE_FORMAT(ropainfantil.Fecha,'%d | %m | %Y') Fecha , COUNT(imagenes.Id_Imagen) Imagenes FROM ropainfantil LEFT JOIN imagenes ON ropainfantil.Id_Album=imagenes.Id_Album GROUP BY ropainfantil.Id_Album;";       
            
        if($Consulta = mysql_query($SQL)){          
            while($Album = mysql_fetch_array($Consulta)){
            
    echo('<Div Class="AlbumCargado"><Div Class="AlbCarDer"><B>'.$Album['Fecha'].'</B><Div Class="AlbCarIz"><H4>'.$Album['Descripcion'].'</H4> <H4>PRECIO:'.$Album['precio'].' €</H4> <I>'.$Album['Imagenes'].' Imagenes.</I></Div><A Href="registro.php?Id_Album='.$Album['Id_Album'].'">VER:LAS FOTOS</A><A Href="GestionAlbum.php?Id_Album='.$Album['Id_Album'].'"></A><A Href="BorrarAlbum.php?Id_Album='.$Album['Id_Album'].'"></A></Div><Div Class="AlbCarImg">');
                
                $SQL = "SELECT Direccion  FROM imagenes WHERE Id_Album='$Album[Id_Album]' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;";
                if($Imagenes = mysql_query($SQL)){                  
                    while($Imagen = mysql_fetch_array($Imagenes)){
                        echo('<Img Src="'.$Imagen['Direccion'].'"/>');
                                                
                    }                   
                } else {
                    echo('No se pudieron obtener las imagenes.');
                }
                
                echo('</Div></Div>');
            }
        } else {
            echo('No se pudieron obtener los albumes.');
        }
    } else {
        echo('No se pudo conectar a la base de datos.');    
    }
    
    
?>
```

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Por favor, un gran consejo al publicar preguntas, quita siempre los datos sensibles de tus conexiones (USUARIO y CLAVE), aquí no todos son buenos...

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo pasarte por [ask] y realizar el [tour]. También deberías [edit] tu pregunta, recuerda que las mayúsculas en internet se interpretan como GRITOS, no apecete mucho ayudar a una persona que te está gritando.